# kruskal wallis significativo (kruskal.test) y dunn test (dunn.test) no significativo en R

Tags: r

Soy nueva en el uso del lenguaje de programación R y he intentado con éste hacer un Kruskal Wallis y luego un Dunn test (con corrección Bonferroni) usando datos de 6 especies de peces, 15 meses de muestreo, diferente número de muestras (entre 25 y 45 réplicas por mes) entre meses y la naturaleza de los datos es de número de animales presentes en un determinado espacio. Mis muestras no son ni normales ni homocedásticas (he intentado las transformaciones tipo log y raíz cuadrada sin éxito). Quiero saber qué meses son diferentes a qué meses para cada una de las especies. Tengo 3 problemas relacionados con el dunn test:

1. El Kruskal Wallis (package kruskal.test) para el pez rockfish me dió un p-valor de 0.01, por lo tanto significativo (existen diferencias de medias significativas entre  meses). Sorprendentemente el dunn test (package dunn.test) no me dió ninguna combinación de grupos (en este caso meses) con p valor significativo.
2. Para el pez *Anoplopoma fimbria* el problema fué otro. Kruskal Wallis me dió un p-valor significativo pero en test de dunn en determinadas combinaciones de meses, digamos A-B por poner un nombre genérico a una pareja de meses me dió un p-valor fué no significativo y B-A (la misma combinación en orden opuesto) me dió significativo. Ocurrió lo mismo con un mes determinado (al que llamaré de forma genérica A) con el mismo mes (la combinación A con A y la combinación A con A de nuevo). Ésto se ha repetido para las demás especies.
3. Intenté una alfa= 0.05 para el test de dunn y repetí de nuevo con una alfa= 0.01 para ver si los resultados eran menos caóticos (muchas combinaciones de meses posibles). El resultado fué exactamente el mismo. Los mismos p valores.

Si ayuda aquí dejo el script que usé y el resultado que me dió para rockfish y más abajo para *Anoplopoma fimbria*:

```
> rockfish.krustal.wallis <-read.table(file.choose(), header=T)
> names(rockfish.krustal.wallis)
> library("dunn.test", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
> dunn.test(rockfish$counts, g=rockfish$months, kw=TRUE, method = "Bonferroni", alpha = 0.01)
```

## El resultado del Kruskal Wallis para rockfish:

```
  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data: x and group
    Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 29.2316, df = 13, p-value = 0.01
```

## Aquí el resultado del dunn test para rockfish:

```
    Comparison of x by group                            
                                     (Bonferroni)                                  
    Col Mean-|
    Row Mean |      apr13      apr14      aug13      des13      feb13      feb14
    ---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
       apr14 |   0.879015
             |     1.0000
             |
       aug13 |   0.832672  -0.060825
             |     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       des13 |   1.187794   0.273902   0.341798
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       feb13 |   0.771037  -0.080607  -0.022883  -0.348631
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       feb14 |  -1.034189  -1.895217  -1.866861  -2.238531  -1.757098
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       jan14 |   0.850220  -0.050744   0.010750  -0.333754   0.033296   1.892852
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       jul13 |   2.160807   1.209424   1.296702   0.963946   1.255722   3.234036
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0555
             |
       jun13 |   1.057552   0.167672   0.231966  -0.103183   0.244048   2.082939
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       mar13 |  -0.629163  -1.587098  -1.552930  -1.964295  -1.440244   0.518166
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       may13 |   0.467668  -0.412120  -0.357916  -0.702341  -0.318816   1.493055
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       nov13 |   2.297948   1.364141   1.451952   1.128504   1.405573   3.348685
             |     0.9812     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0369
             |
       oct13 |   1.566284   0.660026   0.733611   0.403551   0.722355   2.600473
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.4236
             |
       sep13 |   2.415561   1.502453   1.589976   1.276179   1.539858   3.440949
             |     0.7148     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0264
    Col Mean-|
    Row Mean |      jan14      jul13      jun13      mar13      may13      nov13
    ---------+------------------------------------------------------------------
       jul13 |   1.296949
             |     1.0000
             |
       jun13 |   0.223169  -1.044262
             |     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       mar13 |  -1.580526  -3.077551  -1.793553
             |     1.0000     0.0950     1.0000
             |
       may13 |  -0.371446  -1.656015  -0.584947   1.140412
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       nov13 |   1.453266   0.189546   1.203587   3.200510   1.802746
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0624     1.0000
             |
       oct13 |   0.728849  -0.535397   0.495401   2.366799   1.085285  -0.706602
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.8164     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       sep13 |   1.592075   0.364092   1.346645   3.297191   1.931592   0.175774
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0444     1.0000     1.0000
    Col Mean-|
    Row Mean |      aug13      des13      feb13      feb14      jan14      jul13      jun13      mar13      may13      nov13      oct13
    ---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       des13 |   0.341798   0.771037  -0.080607  -0.022883  -0.348631  -1.034189  -1.895217  -1.866861  -2.238531  -1.757098   0.850220
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       feb13 |  -0.022883  -0.348631  -1.034189  -1.895217  -1.866861  -2.238531  -1.757098   0.850220  -0.050744   0.010750  -0.333754
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       feb14 |  -1.866861  -2.238531  -1.757098   0.850220  -0.050744   0.010750  -0.333754   0.033296   1.892852   2.160807   1.209424
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       jan14 |   0.010750  -0.333754   0.033296   1.892852   2.160807   1.209424   1.296702   0.963946   1.255722   3.234036   1.296949
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0555     1.0000
             |
       jul13 |   1.296702   0.963946   1.255722   3.234036   1.296949   1.057552   0.167672   0.231966  -0.103183   0.244048   2.082939
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0555     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       jun13 |   0.231966  -0.103183   0.244048   2.082939   0.223169  -1.044262  -0.629163  -1.587098  -1.552930  -1.964295  -1.440244
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       mar13 |  -1.552930  -1.964295  -1.440244   0.518166  -1.580526  -3.077551  -1.793553   0.467668  -0.412120  -0.357916  -0.702341
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0950     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       may13 |  -0.357916  -0.702341  -0.318816   1.493055  -0.371446  -1.656015  -0.584947   1.140412   2.297948   1.364141   1.451952
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.9812     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       nov13 |   1.451952   1.128504   1.405573   3.348685   1.453266   0.189546   1.203587   3.200510   1.802746   1.566284   0.660026
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0369     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0624     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
             |
       oct13 |   0.733611   0.403551   0.722355   2.600473   0.728849  -0.535397   0.495401   2.366799   1.085285  -0.706602   2.415561
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.4236     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.8164     1.0000     1.0000     0.7148
             |
       sep13 |   1.589976   1.276179   1.539858   3.440949   1.592075   0.364092   1.346645   3.297191   1.931592   0.175774   0.862608
             |     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0264     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0444     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000
```

## El script para *Anoplopoma fimbria*:

```
> rockfish.krustal.wallis <-read.table(file.choose(), header=T)
> names(rockfish.krustal.wallis)
> library("dunn.test", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
> dunn.test(Anoplopoma_fimbria.krustal.wallis$counts, g=Anoplopoma_fimbria.krustal.wallis$months, kw=TRUE, method = "Bonferroni", alpha = 0.01)
```

## El resultado del Kruskal Wallis test:

```
Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data: x and group
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 346.7977, df = 13, p-value = 0
```

## El resultado del dunn test para Anoplopoma fimbria:

```
                          Comparison of x by group                                                                          
                                 (Bonferroni)                                                                               
Col Mean-|                                              
Row Mean |      apr13      apr14      aug13      des13      feb13      feb14                                                
---------+------------------------------------------------------------------                                                
   apr14 |  -0.138335                                               
         |     1.0000                                               
         |                                              
   aug13 |  -5.721434  -5.397150                                                
         |     0.0000     0.0000                                                
         |                                              
   des13 |   0.032365   0.169603   5.753273                                             
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000                                             
         |                                              
   feb13 |   1.137404   1.233460   6.490391   1.107091                                              
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000                                              
         |                                              
   feb14 |   1.256426   1.351363   6.867965   1.224587   0.057956                                               
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                               
         |                                              
   jan14 |   0.770631   0.882201   6.435592   0.738524  -0.406975  -0.488439                                                
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                                
         |                                              
   jul13 |  -8.945967  -8.377165  -2.085009  -8.983885  -9.496393  -10.21129                                                
         |     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                                
         |                                              
   jun13 |  -6.948265  -6.588580  -1.257306  -6.979824  -7.639835  -8.066820                                                
         |     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                                
         |                                              
   mar13 |   1.345278   1.441622   7.566550   1.309824   0.013835  -0.052773                                                
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                                
         |                                              
   may13 |  -3.802618  -3.551380   1.735224  -3.833581  -4.674006  -4.949562                                                
         |     0.0065     0.0174     1.0000     0.0057     0.0001     0.0000                                                
         |                                              
   nov13 |  -3.099127  -2.855706   2.672702  -3.131493  -4.040003  -4.305158                                                
         |     0.0883     0.1954     0.3424     0.0791     0.0024     0.0008                                                
         |                                              
   oct13 |   0.677506   0.791471   6.298163   0.645667  -0.485328  -0.569802                                                
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                                
         |                                              
   sep13 |  -0.235718  -0.092986   5.351330  -0.267277  -1.333887  -1.458183                                                
         |     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                                
Col Mean-|                                              
Row Mean |      jan14      jul13      jun13      mar13      may13      nov13                                                
---------+------------------------------------------------------------------                                                
   jul13 |  -9.748741                                               
         |     0.0000                                               
         |                                              
   jun13 |  -7.647328   0.577645                                                
         |     0.0000     1.0000                                                
         |                                              
   mar13 |   0.489597   11.82495   8.879660                                             
         |     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                             
         |                                              
   may13 |  -4.512609   4.040237   2.945542  -5.406943                                              
         |     0.0003     0.0024     0.1467     0.0000                                              
         |                                              
   nov13 |  -3.845064   5.315158   3.926306  -4.740202   0.837716                                               
         |     0.0055     0.0000     0.0039     0.0001     1.0000                                               
         |                                              
   oct13 |  -0.086014   9.537097   7.501867  -0.579365   4.394957   3.726238                                                
         |     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0005     0.0088                                                
         |                                              
   sep13 |  -0.985667   8.370717   6.553333  -1.562332   3.489703   2.786240                                                
         |     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0220     0.2426                                                
Col Mean-|                                              
Row Mean |      aug13      des13      feb13      feb14      jan14      jul13      jun13      mar13      may13      nov13      oct13                                             
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                             
   des13 |   5.753273   1.137404   1.233460   6.490391   1.107091   1.256426   1.351363   6.867965   1.224587   0.057956   0.770631                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                             
         |                                              
   feb13 |   6.490391   1.107091   1.256426   1.351363   6.867965   1.224587   0.057956   0.770631   0.882201   6.435592   0.738524                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000                                             
         |                                              
   feb14 |   6.867965   1.224587   0.057956   0.770631   0.882201   6.435592   0.738524  -0.406975  -0.488439  -8.945967  -8.377165                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                             
         |                                              
   jan14 |   6.435592   0.738524  -0.406975  -0.488439  -8.945967  -8.377165  -2.085009  -8.983885  -9.496393  -10.21129  -9.748741                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                             
         |                                              
   jul13 |  -2.085009  -8.983885  -9.496393  -10.21129  -9.748741  -6.948265  -6.588580  -1.257306  -6.979824  -7.639835  -8.066820                                             
         |     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000                                             
         |                                              
   jun13 |  -1.257306  -6.979824  -7.639835  -8.066820  -7.647328   0.577645   1.345278   1.441622   7.566550   1.309824   0.013835                                             
         |     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                             
         |                                              
   mar13 |   7.566550   1.309824   0.013835  -0.052773   0.489597   11.82495   8.879660  -3.802618  -3.551380   1.735224  -3.833581                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0065     0.0174     1.0000     0.0057                                             
         |                                              
   may13 |   1.735224  -3.833581  -4.674006  -4.949562  -4.512609   4.040237   2.945542  -5.406943  -3.099127  -2.855706   2.672702                                             
         |     1.0000     0.0057     0.0001     0.0000     0.0003     0.0024     0.1467     0.0000     0.0883     0.1954     0.3424                                             
         |                                              
   nov13 |   2.672702  -3.131493  -4.040003  -4.305158  -3.845064   5.315158   3.926306  -4.740202   0.837716   0.677506   0.791471                                             
         |     0.3424     0.0791     0.0024     0.0008     0.0055     0.0000     0.0039     0.0001     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000                                             
         |                                              
   oct13 |   6.298163   0.645667  -0.485328  -0.569802  -0.086014   9.537097   7.501867  -0.579365   4.394957   3.726238  -0.235718                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0005     0.0088     1.0000                                             
         |                                              
   sep13 |   5.351330  -0.267277  -1.333887  -1.458183  -0.985667   8.370717   6.553333  -1.562332   3.489703   2.786240  -0.893230                                             
         |     0.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     1.0000     0.0000     0.0000     1.0000     0.0220     0.2426     1.0000
```

Comment: Hola crldoya. Entiendo que conoces el idioma español. Te pido por favor que termines de redactar tu pregunta en español. No te preocupes si tienes problemas de cómo aplicar formato al texto, algún miembro en la comunidad te puede apoyar con eso. Pero por favor trata de publicar preguntas completas y que provean la información necesaria para poder responderlas o darte ideas sobre una posible solución. Existe un enlace al pie de la pregunta llamado **editar**, selecciónalo para que puedas editar el contenido de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Luiggi. Gracias por hacerme notar que la pregunta estaba incompleta y gracias por tus recomendaciones. Sigo sin poder cambiar el formato del resultado del dunn test que ahora mismo es ilegible

Comment: Para los que votan por cerrar: si no entienden de qué se trata el lenguaje de programación R ni para qué sirve, por favor **EVITEN** votar por cierre. Votar una pregunta por desconocimiento de cómo resolverla **NO ES LO MISMO QUE** votar porque la pregunta esté mal formulada y no se entienda lo que solicitan.

Comment: Hola Luiggi, he editado la pregunta porque veo que te parecía mal formulada. Creo que se entiende bien ahora pero si algo no se entiende por favor, díganmelo. Sigo sin saber cómo mantener un formato adequado para los resultados del dunn test así que pido disculpas por ello.

Answer (score 2):

Como vez en las tablas que resultan de tu test de Dunn, haces una corrección Bonferroni a los resultados. Cuando comparas, como en tu caso, 13 promedios entre ellos, entre las 13 x 13 = 169 comparaciones. Te podrás imaginar que el chance de que algo se parezca al azar es mas grande cuando comparas 13 grupos a, por ejemplo, comparar solo 2 promedios (2 x 2 = 4 combinaciones en vez de 169).

En términos técnicos estas perdiendo grados de libertad al incrementar el numero comparaciones. Y en la práctica la solución más común es una corrección Bonferroni como lo haces arriba.

Por lo mismo, no te debería sorprender que un resultado significativo con Kruskal Wallis, no resulta en resultados significativos con Dunn cuando tienes 13 grupos. Para ver differencias al nivel de grupos el resultado sugiere que necesitas mas datos.

La siguiente pregunta es obviamente como seguir con estos datos? Mi respuesta sería: mira otra vez bien cual fue tu diseño de muestreo y porque. Parece que el diseño en este caso fue para ver si hay un efecto del mes, y no para determinar las diferencias entre meses.

Tienes soporte para concluir que hay un efecto significativo del mes con el resultado del Kruskal Wallis. Una tendencia mensual quizás se deja ver en una gráfica. Aunque no le puedas asignar un significancia estadística, puedes describir la tendencia en los datos con una interpretación visual.

Por lo general no tiene mucho sentido buscar y buscar un método estadístico
hasta que encuentres uno que te de los resultados que quieras ver. Es mejor tomar los resultados como base para un mejor diseño de muestreo la próxima vez, o como base para recomendar un mejor diseño cuando publiques estos resultados

Comment: Hola FvD, gracias por tu respuesta. Qué solución me recomiendas? Me es imposible tener más datos.

Comment: La autora de del Dunn.test me recomienda usar el kruskal Wallis  y luego, en lugar del dunn test usar el Conover-Iman test que tiene *más* potencia estadística. Usarlo con la corrección de Holm (si se prefiere controlar el family-wise error rate ) o la de  Benjamini-Yekutiel( si se prefiere para controlar false discovery rate). Lo que no sé es qué es preferible controlar en este caso...

Comment: Creo que mejor controlar el family-wise error rate no? Puesto que el error tipo I es muy elevado con tantas combinaciones...

Comment: Hola de nuevo FvD, repetí el análisis agrupando los meses en estaciones reduciendo considerablemente el número de comparaciones pero sigue siendo un sin sentido. Hice un conover-Iman test con corrección de Holm pero me dió igual que el dunn test con estaciones. He abierto otra pregunta con los resultados del conover-Iman test

Comment: Hola @crldoya, en efecto es una nueva pregunta. Si puedes ver un efecto mensual en tus gráficas de los datos ya tienes suficiente para describirlo y argumentar el porque del patron que observas. Añadi sugerencias en la respuesta.